# Using jsonRest with filteringSelect widget

Tags: dojo

I start working onchanging all widgets that can be rebuild using jsonRest rather than Memory, like filteringSelect and Dgrid in my app.
After I fixed the filteringSelect, replaced the memory with jsonRest and tested that it works well, I tried to use store/cache with it. 
the testing showed that caching is not happening, and when I searched the web, I got with someone's answer:

**http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/How-to-use-FilteringSelect-with-a-JsonRest-store-and-a-Cache-store-td3994386.html**

this issue tells that cache not working with filteringSelect, but I need to use request. 
on the other hand, "request" requests the data immediately so it's not an option.

Can you give the right answer: 
1. Does cache work with jsonRest on filteringSelect? 
2. Can I use dgrid with jsonRest and cache also?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

While `JsonRest` can be used with `Cache` just fine (regardless of what widget consumes it), the important thing to consider (which that mailing list post points out) is that `dojo/store/Cache` does not cache `query` calls to the store, only `get` calls, since `query` calls can include any variety of range, filter, and sort parameters.  So I don't think you'd get the effect out of using `Cache` that you're expecting.

If your service doesn't have a large number of records, another option would be to use [dojo-smore's](https://github.com/kfranqueiro/dojo-smore) RequestMemory store, which is essentially a middle ground between `Memory` and `JsonRest` - it requests the full data set once (though it does request it as soon as the store is created), but then stores the entire set in memory for all `query` and `get` calls.

Comment: Can I use jsonRest with 'GET'only, on filteringSelect widget?  
Is there a live example of that? when I use it with filteringSelect, it seems like there is no way to tell JR to work with GET method. the POST query happens automatically.
On the other hand, I have a lot of data. using dojo-smore is not an option for me.

Comment: That doesn't sound right...  Both the `query` and `get` methods of `JsonRest` issue GET requests to the server.  FilteringSelect uses the store's `query` method for populating the drop-down.